# is it POSSIBLE to downgrade 17.04 to Gtk-2?

Tags: eclipse, 17.04, gtk3, gtk-2

I have a critical eclipse-based app that is not playing well with Gtk-3; product support says they've received many issues that are solved by downgrading.

Is it possible to downgrade Zesty to Gtk-2? Is it possible to put their app in a wrapper that would force Gtk-2? Or am I forced to reinstall 16.10?

Comment: No. And I would install a virtual box session and install an operating system in there that has gtk 2

Comment: No. Not even 16.04

Answer (score 1):

If this is an app that uses swing you might well find that setting the environment variable `SWT_GTK3=0` will resolve your issues. If that works at the command line and you have an ini file along the lines of `eclipse.ini` then include the two lines below

```
--launcher.GTK_version

2
```